# My Website Loads Really Slow Using Domain Name, But Fast Using IP

Tags: domain, ip, website, address

Only fixed line ISP is affected. Others OK. Anyone knows where to start to detect the problem?. DNS Checked using DIG TRACERT NSLOOKUP WHOIS all OK. is there anything i need to check at my hosting dedicated server? using linux ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your forward dns lookup is fast, but your server lags when serving content and you accessed via dns name, then likely the server itself is attempting reverse dns lookup of the client and failing.  It could be your web server daemon and/or any scripts you may be serving (php, perl, python, etc) attempting and **failing** to look up the client.   Check /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/nsswitch.conf on your server.

To test, try adding the IP you are accessing from in /etc/hosts with a static name.